# How to tell the amount of days from now until an NSDate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, nsdate

How can I tell the amount of days from now until the date specified in my app? Here is what I have so far, but it comes up with "-30" every time, no matter what the date is:

```
NSDate * selected = [DatePicker date];
NSString * date = [selected description];

NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                                              fromDate:DatePicker.date];

CalLabel1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [components day]];

NSDateFormatter *temp = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[temp setDateFormat:@"dd/MM/yyyy"];
NSDate *stDt = [temp dateFromString:[temp stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];
NSDate *endDt =  [temp dateFromString:[temp stringFromDate:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [components date]]]];
unsigned int unitFlags = NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSDayCalendarUnit;
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                         initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components:unitFlags fromDate:stDt  toDate:endDt  options:0];
int days = [comps day];

NSLog(@"%i", [comps day]);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
NSDate * selected = [DatePicker date];
NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] 
                          initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components: NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                       fromDate: [NSDate date]  
                                         toDate: selected  
                                        options: 0];
int days = [comps day];

NSLog(@"%i", [comps day]);
```

This calculates the number of days between now and the selected date. All your messing around with the date formatter was wrong and not necessary.

Comment: This is better in general because it takes any relevant quirks of the calendar into consideration.

Answer (score 3):

What about just using `-timeIntervalSinceNow` on `NSDate`?

```
NSDate *selectedDate = [datePicker date];
NSTimeInterval numberOfSecondsUntilSelectedDate = [selectedDate timeIntervalSinceNow];
NSInteger numberOfDays = numberOfSecondsUntilSelectedDate / 86400; // 86,400 seconds in a day
```

Comment: +1 - but it might be easier to read if 86400 was a constant or something like (60 * 60 * 24) was written.

Comment: Agreed. I would use a constant in production code but I felt that a comment sufficed for demonstration purposes.

Comment: Better to use the calendar API instead of doing the calculations by hand. This is easy for days, but once you want to know weeks or months this is not trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3 version of the accepted answer.

```
let dateComponents = Calendar.current.dateComponents([.day], from: fromDate, to: Date())

// number of days is an optional Int
if let daysCount = dateComponents.day {
    print(daysCount)
}
```