# Interval between 2 NSDates

Tags: xcode, nsdate

I am trying to calculate an interval between now and a user defined date in days so that the results appear in a label on tapping a button.

The difference is always -4080 I am not sure what is wrong with my equation.
Thank you for your help

```
- (void)LabelChange2:(id)sender{
    NSDateFormatter *df3 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    df3.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
    labelDOB.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
                     [df3 stringFromDate:datepick.date]];
}



  NSDate * df3 = [datePick date];
    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc] 
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSGregorianCalendar];
    NSDateComponents *comps = [gregorian components: NSDayCalendarUnit 
                                           fromDate: [NSDate date]  
                                             toDate: df3 
                                            options: 0];
    int days = [comps day];
    labelResult.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", days];
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to tell the amount of days from now until an NSDate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7959243/how-to-tell-the-amount-of-days-from-now-until-an-nsdate)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code works fine. However if I run the code with the `datePick` pointer set to `nil` I will get an answer of `-4080` from this code. You should check your connections to the `UIDatePicker`.

Comment: Yes. 4080 days ago was January 1st 2001. Which is the base of NSDate. So a nil date will yield 4080 days ago. Tomorrow it will be -4081

Comment: Yes of course, how did I not recognize my old friend Reference Date. Star of such methods as: `timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate` & `dateWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate:`

Comment: @NJones, thanks heaps turns out a capitalized P in date picker in
UIDatePicker *datePick;
as opposed to
 property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UIDatePicker *datepick;